# Constructing measures by any function from $X$ to $[0,+\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis

This is an example in Real Analysis by Folland.
Let $X$ be any nonempty set, $\mathcal{M}$=$\mathcal{P}(X)$, and $f$ any function from $X$ to $[0,+\infty]$. Then $f$ determines a measure on $\mathcal{M}$: $\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E}f(x)$. Where the sum of uncountable set is the supremum of finite sums. To show the countable additivity, I can prove one (easy) direction and got stuck with the other direction. How to show the other direction or provide some advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to use the counting measure. The measure you're describing is defined via integrating $f$ over the subsets of $X$, and hence satisfies the axioms of a measure.

Comment: I saw it in the following part of the book. It is actually the integral of f on E, using counting measure. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! That result is sometimes known as the "law of the unconscious statistician", since it can be used to compute the average of a random variable of the form $f(X)$. It appears very often, so try to keep it in mind!